# Facebook の Graph API で日本語表記の名前を取得する

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-api

PHP で Facebook の Graph API を使って日本語表記の名前を取得しようとしています。
Google で検索すると、

> Graph APIを用い、me?locale=ja_JPとするだけでも、日本語で情報を取得できるようです。

という記事を見つけ

```
//ユーザー情報取得
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me&locale=ja_JP','GET');
//出力
print_r($user_profile);
```

としましたが

```
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: me&locale=ja_JP
```

というエラーになってしまいました。

もちろん

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

ではうまく実行できています。

どうすれば日本語表記の名前を取得することができるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リクエストの URL が以下のようになっていますが
`'/me&locale=ja_JP'`

正しくは

`'/me?locale=ja_JP'`

`&` ではなく、`?` です。